# OpenCV: Face detection taking advantage of a command line

Tags: python, opencv, command-line, openbr

I run this (first one) [example](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) that launches the webcam of my latop so that I can see myself on the screen.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I installed [OpenBr](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.htmlhttp://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.html) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I run successfully [this](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/group__cli.html) command on a picture of myself:

```
br - gui -algorithm ShowFaceDetection -enrollAll -enroll /home/nakkini/Desktop/myself.png
```

The above command I run on the Terminal displays my picture and draws a square around my face (face detection), it also  highlights my eyes in green.

**My Dream:**

I wonder if there is a way to combine this command with the short program above so that when the webcam is launched I can see my face surrounded by the green rectangle ?

**Why do I need this ?**

I found similar programs in pure OpenCV/Python for this purpos. However, for later needs, I need more things than the simple face detection and I judge by myself that OpenBR will save me lot of headache. That is why I am looking for a way to run the command line somewhere inside the code above as a first but big step.

**Hints:**

The `frame` in the code corresponds to `myself.png` of the command line. The solution to be found will try to pass `frame` in the place of `myself.png` to the command line within the program itself.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

After correcting the typos of @Xavier's solution I have no errors. However the program does not run as I want it:

First, the camer is launched and I see myself but my face is not detected with a green rectangle. Secondly,  I press any key to exit but the program does not exit: it shows me a picture of myself with my face detected. A last key press exists the program. My goal is to see my face detected during the camera functionment.

Comment: you got a space between - and gui, it should probably be: `br -gui ...` not `br - gui`

Comment: @berak nice observation but I corrected it previously. Thank you

Comment: @berak you can see my third edit in case you have time. Thank you

Comment: Split the problem into two parts: 1) given a video file, do the face tracking. 2) Plug that into the video camera.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need openbr for this at all.

just see opencv's [python face-detect tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)

Comment: I already run similar codes using pure OpenCV capabilities in Python. However I would love to achieve what I asked. But I thnak you very much for the interesting link.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.imwrite( "/home/nakkini/Desktop/myself.png", gray );
        os.system('br - gui -algorithm -ShowFaceDetection -enrollAll -enroll /home/nakkini/Desktop/myself.png')
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I try on my other machine I will let you know. But I think you wanted to write `imread()` instead of `imwrite()` ?

Comment: The point is that `br` is waiting for a file and `cv2.imwrite()` is creating it

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right about that. I just get an error about `system` it is not recognized but I will check on internet .. i think i found something like `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: forget import os;os.system(...)

Comment: don't forget the import os at top of script

Comment: Yes, I imported everything necessary. Thank you. I edited in my question the error I get and the behavior, in case you have time . Thank you

Comment: You almost did it ! Now it shows my face  in the camera. Nothing happens but when I exit the program it shows first a picture of myself with my eyes and face detected ! then i must press a key again to exitfully the progam